# Why wouldn't the JIT compile the whole program over time?

Tags: java, c#, jvm, compiler-optimization, jit

Consider a JIT programming language like Java or C#.
It is known the VM (e.g. the JVM) uses some metrics to decide which code parts need a speed-up and it compiles it to machine code.

My question is, if we consider a long running process like an HTTP server, wouldn't it be better to compile the whole process over time? Are there any downsides to JIT compiling?

Comment: [ngen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator)...

Comment: JIT compilation requires memory and CPU time -- memory to track the optimization properties of the compiled code, and to hold the compiled code; CPU time to perform the optimization work.  Consider tasks like setting up the server for the first time -- those are never going to run more than once for the lifetime of the process; you'll never need to optimize them.

Comment: I think before the question is re-open Elimination needs to clarify what research they already done (https://www.bing.com/search?q=jit+vs+aot+java) and what exactly they want to get answer to here. List of differenced between .Net JIT and Java JIT (or different Java JIT implementations) alone is far too long for SO, comparing all JITs to all AoT implementations is way too broad.

Comment: All parts of the code that actually run often will get JIT compiled.  If they never run, or only run once during startup or exit, no point spending CPU time and memory now to JIT compile them.  (I guess you're thinking that it would make sense to JIT compile some part of the code that's *going to* run, e.g. some data analysis that will run after some collection interval, but JIT compilers also rely on profiling info which isn't available for code that's never executed.)